# Bootstrap vertical grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a question about how to put stuff vertical in a grid system with bootstrap.
Here is what I'm trying to do:
first, the screen should be devided in two part horinzontally, left part 8, right part 4. 
then, the left part should be devided again vertically, on the top side there will be a table in it. 
on the bottom part, again devided in 2 horizontally ane in each part a panel will be shown. 
[[image: 1]]

**How do I do the vertical part?**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8" id="leftside">
      ?
      ?
      ?
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" id="rightside">
      ...
   </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="height:500px;background-color:green;">
      <div class="row" style="height:50%;background-color:red;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>A</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <p>B</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" >
          <p>C</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:500px;background-color:black">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Codepen:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYVxGa

Answer (score 2):

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"> <!-- leftside -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:blue;">table</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow;">panel1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:green;">panel2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:red;height:40px">rightside</div> <!-- rightside -->
  </div>

<hr>
<!-- code without bg-color -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"> <!-- leftside -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">table</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">panel1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">panel2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:40px">rightside</div> <!-- rightside -->
  </div>
```

Note: Make sure that you will have to give custom height to "rightside" column.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/AnoNewb/pen/zjebGb